# How are AutoIT variable names stored after compiling it to a executable?

Tags: windows, malware

I need to write a yara rule for a autoit malware (the binary itself not the decompiled script)

As far as i know the actual script is in the resource section in the RCData, but how can i find the bytes that represent the variable names?

for example lets say there is a variable $MyObviousVariable in the script and i want to make a yara rule for it in the binary, where can i find this variable NAME in the binary? is it inside the RCData?